# Are there any good googlemaps plugins for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

There are some good geocoding plugins (e.g. geokit) but can you recommend a googlemaps plugin for "the view" in rails?

I used YM4R/GM before but I don't know if its still up to date...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always just used GeoKit for all things GoogleMaps... it's a little old, but all the source code for "Beginning Google Maps Applications with Rails" is available at http://googlemapsbook.com/source/. It should walk you through pretty well on how to write the code for the front end. [Advanced Rails Recipes](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/advanced-rails-recipes) also has some great code recipes on building geocoded points into GoogleMaps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on Github I found [google_maps](http://github.com/bhedana/google_maps/tree/master) plugin. I haven't tried it but it seems ok.